# Can a class inherit an interface from its superclass?

Tags: java

Suppose we have the two classes given below:

```
public class baseclass implements interface {}
public class subclass extends baseclass{}
```

Does the subclass also inherit the interface from the baseclass?

Regards,
Shreyas

Comment: You can only tell the difference using the reflection library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it inherits interface from baseclass.

Simple example would be, if you don't implement any methods defined in interface in `baseclass`. Your `subclass` need to implement them otherwise define as abstract class.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Subtyping in Java is transitive: if `A` is a subtype of `B` and `B` is a subtype of `C`, then `A` is a subtype of `C`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does.

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html):

> A class necessarily implements all the interfaces that its direct superclasses and direct superinterfaces do.

Comment: @ShreyasD The Java Language Specification '*seems* to be true'?